# Another jQuery noob question about functions

Tags: jquery, function, each, loops

I want to "functionalize" more of my jQuery code, instead of writing little standalone snippets. Here's an example. Let's say I have some li's that I'd like to use as triggers, like so:

```
<li class="alpha-init" id="a-init">A</li>
<li class="alpha-init" id="b-init">B</li>
<li class="alpha-init" id="c-init">C</li>
```

And some stuff I'd like to hide and show in correspondence to clicks on those triggers, like so:

```
<ul id="a-sub" class="alpha-popdown">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="b-sub" class="alpha-popdown">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>


<ul id="c-sub" class="alpha-popdown">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

If I wanted to write a little snippet for each case, I could do:

```
$('li.alpha-init #a-init').click(function(){
    $('ul#a-sub').slideToggle(200);
}
```

But that means writing as many snippets as there are sets of links and submenus. How can I write this into a function? I'm not looking to "eat for a day", so as much explanation as you feel up to writing would be much appreciated. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('li.alpha-init').click(function(){
    $('ul#'+this.id.substr(1) + "-sub").slideToggle(200);
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to do the string manipulation, this would be a case where I would consider storing the related ul ID value in the 'rel' attribute of the alpha-init elements then replace the substr call above with this.attr("rel")

Comment: This is excellent. I was thinking of something else all together, like arrays and each(), but this works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) for this? It sounds nearly exactly like what you want. You can just style the tabs differently than the default!

Comment: jQuery UI has some really nice tricks, but it can also be overkill for simple effects, and it also doesn't help 'littlerobothead' here learn anything.

Comment: True. Though UI Tabs might be the right path to go down depending on his requirements.

Comment: I'm using jQuery UI on this project for a few things, but the overhead is awfully steep. I was hoping to edge ever closer to building some plugins and functions of my own, and this seemed like a good thought problem to help me start down that road.

Comment: No worries. Make sure you're using Google AJAX Libraries (http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery) to serve jQuery and jQuery UI if possible - that will reduce your overhead and make sure your libraries are served as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First off, id's should be unique on your page. You only need to use the selector `$('#a-init')` to access it.

I would write that like so (for each item):

html:

```
<li class="alpha-init" id="a-init">
<div>A</div>
<ul id="a-sub" class="alpha-popdown">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

And then write the jquery as:

```
$('li.alpha-init').click(function(){
    $(this).children('ul.alpha-popdown').slideToggle(200);
}
```

The basic idea would be to use the $(this) method to access the item that was clicked and select your menu element relative to the parent element.

Comment: Have another look at his markup. I'm not sure that the structure of his markup is the same as the solution you've mentioned.

Comment: It's true. Depending what he's doing, my markup change could change the actual effect/layout/meaning of the page. Artem's solution is the best here.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of Artem Barger and John Sheehan's code. Thanks everyone for your help; now I get to sleep!